# Enable scope permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a signed URL following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File#getSignedUrl) but I fail to understand how to enable the scope for my Cloud Function.

I am sure that my Cloud Function has **cloudfunctions.serviceAgent** which includes `signBlob`. But then the doc says it needs either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam` or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope which I have no clue how to enable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after randomly trying few things.

- From Console, go to IAM page.
- Click the pencil icon on `your-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` service account. I choose that because the error in GCF Logs Viewer says:

> Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this
>   operation on service account
>   projects/your-project-id/serviceAccounts/**your-project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com**

- Add role `Cloud Functions Service Agent` and done.

The same role, `Cloud Functions Service Agent`, should be assigned to `service-projectnumber@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as well to make sure your function can be created and updated. See [Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors).